# mysql query to select all rows which satisfy a given input range and for multiple inputs

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, multiple-select

I need to find the number of rows which satisfy the given condition for a list of input values.

Suppose we have a table with columns id,open_date,close_date.

**request table**

```
id  open_date      close_date
1   '2013-04-08'   '2013-04-10'
2   '2013-04-11'   '2013-04-12'
1   '2013-04-09'   '2013-04-12'
1   '2013-04-10'   '2013-04-12'
```

Now I would want to the count of the rows which satisfy the condition for a given input x(x is one of the values from the input list) such that x>open_date and x < close_date.

This can be done for a single entry of the list ,x as below

```
SELECT count(*) FROM request WHERE '2013-04-10' BETWEEN open_date AND close_date
```

but how can I do this if for all x where x is an entry from a list ('2013-04-10','2013-04-12') etc.

Though I browsed many post,could not find an answer for this type of question.Can this be done in a single select query ?

Comment: Does the list always contain two elements?

Comment: No,it contains many elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recommended: programmatically generate a massive query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM request WHERE 
    '2013-04-10' BETWEEN open_date AND close_date OR
    '2013-05-10' BETWEEN open_date AND close_date OR
    ....
    '2015-11-4' BETWEEN open_date AND close_date
```

Note: this gives you a total.  If you want a total for each date, you need to do it the second way.

Recommended but a fair bit more complex.  Placing the dates in a table with one column, combining them, filtering out only the sets that match, and then grouping them together to count them.

```
SELECT q.date, COUNT(*) FROM test_dates q, request r
    WHERE q.date BETWEEN r.open_date AND r.close_date
    GROUP BY q.date;
```

Demo sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/474bb/3

Edit:

This variant will, as I think was actually requested, count the number of rows whose range includes any of the test dates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT r.id FROM test_dates q, request r
        WHERE q.date BETWEEN r.open_date AND r.close_date) t;
```

Comment: Bu the first one is the normal way of doing it and which might not be ok for a larger list of values.Yes,I need just the total aggregate count (overlapping is ok).What if we have many inputs.Also what wud be an efficient way for a larger list.Wud it be a procedure at the mysql side or do we have any other approach?

Comment: 1. that's why I said that was not the best way and provided another. 2. You have not specified what you're looking for exactly -- do you want the number of ranges that contain one or more dates?  Do you want the number of ranges surrounding each given date?  Do you want something else?

Comment: I need the count of number of such rows in the db such that any of the row satsifes both >open_date and <close_date of any of the inputs

Comment: , Also,how is the second other than the functionality part better in terms of performance.For every q.date in q,a table scan has to be done on the table r and then the grouping happens right ?

Comment: Edited to include what I think you're looking for.  As for why the table join is better?  SQL tends to be sneaky and will often actually do something smarter than what you told it to.  Thus, joins and so on tend to be faster than hard-coding the same process.  At a minimum it shouldn't be slower, and it will be expandable.  Also, at very large sizes (thousands of dates), parsing the text of the query will start to matter in terms of resource use.

Comment: .  Yes.This is what I exactly wanted.What about the performance of this query ? Of course the sub query is the major one here.

Comment: In all this the only issue I see is I have to maintain a table to insert the values each time I need the count.For any subsequent query's,the table has to b cleaned up and again inserted with the new dates.

Comment: Looks like,this query uses  **Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)** .